# Route filters loading function no matter what

Tags: authentication, laravel, filter, laravel-routing

The problem with this is that the function is loaded whether the user is logged in or not. I need the account function to only be loaded if the user is logged in. I had `Auth::check()` then redirect in the function itself but I was told there was a way to do that within the route.

Route:

```
 Route::get('account', ['before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'SiteController@account']);
```

Standard Auth Filter Laravel:

```
 Route::filter('auth', function()
 {
 if (Auth::guest())
 {
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
    }
    else
    {
        //return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your last attempt should work. Just get rid of the leading slash:

```php
Route::get('account', ['before' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'SiteController@account']);
```

Comment: Not sure if I should edit the question or just make a new one. I checked the filter in `app/filters` and it said if not logged in should give 401 page. Either way the function is being loaded and if not logged in I just get an undefined variable on the next page